# How to get the Current Year to Current date in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, date

How can i get data from the current year to current date.

Like :

Jan 01-01-2014 to March 03-22-2014.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select  *
from    YourTable
where   year(YourColumn) = year(getdate())
        and datepart(dy, YourColumn) <= datepart(dy, getdate())
```